# Access token for foursquare and flickr

Tags: foursquare, flickr

I have the consumer key and consumer secret key for Foursquare and flickr..
I want to get access token and access token secret key..
Can some one help me on this???

Answer (score 1):

To get an access token for a user, the user must authorize your consumer to act on its behalf. See https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/auth for more details on how to accomplish this for foursquare's API.